# Dynamically change styleClass via BooleanCheckBox in JSF

Tags: css, jsf

I am trying to change styleClass dynamically in JSF, and I want it can be controlled by checkbox. So I have tried to use one line if-else condition in styleClass attribute.

```
<h:outputText value="valueText" 
                  styleClass="#{pmBean.check}?header-bold:header-normal" />
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="checkMsisdn" value="#{pmBean.check}">
    <p:ajax process="checkMsisdn" update="rulesForm:formInternal"/>
</p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

What is wrong with the following statement?

```
styleClass="#{pmBean.check}?header-bold:header-normal"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have closed the EL expression before its end. It should be :

```
styleClass="#{pmBean.check ? 'header-bold' : 'header-normal'}"
```

Comment: it solves my problem, but since I have using Ajax call Boolean check does not propagated in styleClass at first. I only have seen the changes after F5. I think there should be one more attribute to be used.

Comment: I assume you will have to update the `outputText` after clicking on the checkbox. Give the `outputText` an id (like `id="outputText"`) and try with `update="outputText"` under the `<p:ajax>`.

Comment: that's it. Thank. It works properly. I have also test that, Changing update="rulesForm:formInternal" to update="@form" works.